# Spring Security with Spring 4

Tags: spring, spring-security, pom.xml

I recently updated my Spring project to Spring 4. After upgrading I am not able to successfully update the Maven project since Spring Security jars are not matching with Spring 4 jars.
Here is dependencies in the POM file.

```
<spring.version>3.2.3.RELEASE</spring.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>compile</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

It is showing missing artifacts on compilation.Please suggest which jars need to be used. Any help will be truly appreciable.

Comment: Spring versions and spring Security versions are quite different, use separate version properties for those...

Comment: You do better provide the whole pom.xml file not a sample... It would be more helpful if you could also mention the error log.